# Flickity - Show 2 slides but only slide 1 at a time

Tags: flickity

I've got a slider where 2 slides should be shown at a time, but when swiping it should only slide 1 at a time, is that possible? I can get it to show 2 at a time, but it then slides 2, to do that I used the groupCells option.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, I ended up using the cellAlign option:

```
<div id="test" class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left"}'>
```

and then set the width of the div to that of two slides.

Answer (score -1):

You could add the code you have in your question to help solve it faster. Anyways, have you tried : `draggable: '>1'` ? That seems to be the way to do it. Then just use CSS `width` to display 2 at a time.